# How can you open a directory/entire folder in Visual Studio Code using command line?

Tags: git-bash

Is there a way to open a folder/directory from git bash/shell emulator? I know you can use 'start' then the file name to open one file, but is there a way to open the entire folder?

Edit: If you're trying to open an entire folder with Visual Studio Code (which is what I was trying to do), follow these steps:

1. Navigate inside the folder in git bash.
2. Then run the command: **code . --new-window**
3. Your project with all files in that folder should open in a new Visual Studio Code window.

Answer (score 24):

Haven't used "Git Bash"... I assume it is a bash shell emulator. If so, try:

```
cd <folder>
```

cd stands for Change Directory.

To open the current folder, try:

```
start .
```

The '.' is the current folder. To open in VS Code try:

```
code .
```

`code` CLI needs to be [installed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-the-visual-studio-code-vs-code-command-line-interface). More info on use [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line).

Comment: Thanks for the reply- cd just changes what directory you're in, but it doesn't open that directory. For example, I'm trying to open a whole project folder in visual studio from a git bash command.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you (@StephanieMcNaught) chose this as the correct answer.

Comment: Hey Robert, your instructions (start .) open the folder in a new file explorer window. I was attempting to open a folder in a new code editor window (Visual Studio Code).

Comment: Haha, okay. Your secondary questions leads people to believe otherwise. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: It simply opens the folder in question in file explorer, does not open in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

I use this alias in my `~/.bashrc` to mirror the `open` functionality I miss from OSX:

```
function open() {
    # if argument != '.', open full-path to argument
    [ "$@" = '.' ] && dir_path="." || dir_path=$(realpath "$@")
    start $dir_path
}
```

You can use it to open relative paths to directories: `open /relativeDirectory`

Here's the same code in an easier to read manner:

```
function open() {
    arg="$@"
    dir_path=$(realpath $arg)
    if [ "$arg" = '.' ]; then
      dir_path="."
    fi
    start $dir_path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. go to the specific folder (cd myFolder)
2. code .